# Getting the range of values where the number of solutions to an equation is equal to a number

Tags: equation-solving

I've been having trouble making a function, which as said in the title, takes in an equation (with a varying variable), and returns the range of values in which the equation has the desired number of solutions.

Similar to the Manipulate function, I want to try all values and then find which values work and then try make a range from there:

```
Manipulate[Length[Solve[Cos[x/n] == x && -10 <= x <= 10] 
  // DeleteDuplicates], {n, -10, 10}]
```

The approach above doesn't work, so I've tried this:

```
GetNumSol[equation_, xdom_ : {x, -10, 10}, solNum_, changevar_ : n, 
  xvar_ : x] := 
 Reduce[Length[Solve[equation && xdom[[2]] <= xdom[[1]] <= xdom[[3]]] 
  // DeleteDuplicates] == solNum, n]
```